# Can I ignore certain fields that are too long in Hirb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console, hirb

I am using Hirb in my Rails console to try to display mongoid records in a nicer looking table, but the `_id`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` fields take too much space and, even though I really have one meaning field, `name`, when I do a `Project.first` it returns a rather disintegrated table:

[image]

Is there any chance that there's a way to 'ignore' or 'hide' certain fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open up hirb, run this:

```
table projects, :fields => [:name]
```

Then `Project.all` and enjoy! ;-)

Also see this: [Hirb - Irb On The Good Stuff](http://tagaholic.me/2009/03/13/hirb-irb-on-the-good-stuff.html).

*UPDATE*:

*"Hirb also supports a yaml configuration file (`config/hirb.yml` or `~/.hirb.yml`)"*

```
  ---
    :output:
      Project:
        :options:
          :fields:
            - name
```

Comment: it works. though I'd prefer not having to type out table ..., :fields => [...] every time I retrieve records. I guess that's the best can be done?

Comment: It is explained in the link in my answer. I'll update the post with that info.